# Using different assets for a different namespace in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4 app that uses the assets in `app/assets/javascripts` and `app/assets/stylesheets` throughout the application. However, I have made a nested resource for the admin portion of the app. I'd like for the admin interface to differ from what the end-user sees (different layout, different assets).

I tried changing the following in my application.css file:

```
*= require_tree .
```

to

```
*= require_directory
```

but the entire app still seems to be using the same resources. Could anyone please illuminate me on how to use different assets for different portions of a Rails 4 app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not how you're including files in your assets manifests, just that you're using the same manifest for the public and private/admin parts of your application.

You should create a new file called `app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css` and include within it the assets you require for your admin layout. Perhaps something like this:

```
*= require_tree ./admin
```

And then change your existing `application.css` not to use `require_tree .` but rather something more specific, such as this:

```
*= require_tree ./main
```

And move all of your public CSS files into that directory within your stylesheets directory.

Finally, you need to create a new layout for your admin pages, or modify the application layout such that the stylesheet and javascript includes are dynamic based on which part of the application you're using.

For simplicity you might want to just go with a new layout for the admin section, called `app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb` and then update any controllers for the application pages to use `layout :admin`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks :) Just one comment, you wrote `require tree ./admin` but it should be `require_tree ./admin` in order to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I know the three combinations

```
 *= require_tree . # for base asset directory
 *= require_tree ./path # a specific path
 *= require filename # some file
```